# Python Solvers for Newton Method Maximization for Higher Dimensions

Tags: python, newtons-method

I am trying to implement the [newton method for maximization in higher dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization) and I was wondering if there exists any solvers for this in Python? In Scipy there is a [solver for the 1-dimensional case](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html), but I do not see one for the multi-dimensional case.  I suppose that it is possible to implement it using the Hessian and Gradient solvers in [Numdifftools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Numdifftools/0.4.0)

EDIT:
It looks like scipy.optimize.minimize does this.  I was looking under the multi-dimensional heading and it wasn't there, that's why I missed it.  It was under the general-purpose heading

Answer (score 0):

scipy.optimize.minimize does this.